# Django Model: how to find list of auto-generated fields

Tags: django, django-models

Is there any Django built-in function that return a list of all auto-generated fields from a Django model?

Something like: MyModel._meta._get_auto_generated_fields()

Comment: What do you mean with "auto-generated"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the fields with *list comprehension* on the [**`.auto_generated`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.auto_created):

```
[field for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if field.auto_created]
```